# Why an anycast server is so far away / slow? How does BGP anycast work?

Tags: dns-hosting, bgp, anycast

I've tried doing a couple of traceroute tests to the DNS servers of Rage4, which are anycasted from many parts of the world (supposedly, from [30 different locations](http://rage4.com/Home/Network)).

What I've experienced is that very often the traceroute shows that the server being contacted is very far away from the querying location, even though a traceroute from another location would show a server that should have been quite close.

For example, from France, we're going to an Indian server:

```
traceroute to ns2.r4ns.com (176.124.113.200), 16 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  88-190-61-1.poneytelecom.eu (88.190.61.1) [AS12322]  2.695 ms  2.876 ms  3.000 ms
 2  a9k2-1041.dc3.poneytelecom.eu (88.191.1.185) [AS12322]  1.178 ms  1.447 ms  1.516 ms
 3  ix-25-0.thar1.PVU-Paris.as6453.net (80.231.63.21) [AS6453]  0.523 ms  0.522 ms  0.516 ms
 4  if-13-5.tcore1.PVU-Paris.as6453.net (80.231.153.177) [AS6453]  11.326 ms  11.310 ms  11.313 ms
 5  if-12-2.tcore1.PYE-Paris.as6453.net (80.231.154.69) [AS6453]  11.306 ms  11.555 ms  11.290 ms
 6  if-8-1600.tcore1.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net (80.231.217.5) [AS6453]  11.405 ms  11.362 ms if-14-2.tcore1.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net (80.231.154.170) [AS6453]  11.350 ms
 7  if-2-2.tcore2.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net (80.231.217.2) [AS6453]  11.326 ms  11.428 ms  11.507 ms
 8  80.231.200.26 (80.231.200.26) [AS6453]  105.722 ms  105.972 ms  107.541 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  14.140.128.98.static-vsnl.net.in (14.140.128.98) [AS4755]  115.191 ms  115.046 ms  115.022 ms
13  ns2.r4ns.com (176.124.113.200) [as198412/AS23033/AS28513/AS61163/AS198412]  116.479 ms  114.806 ms  114.982 ms
```

Or from Germany, it goes Los Angeles, California:

```
traceroute to ns1.r4ns.com (176.124.112.100), 16 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  static.33.203.4.46.clients.your-server.de (46.4.203.33) [AS24940]  0.650 ms  3.633 ms  0.643 ms
 2  hos-tr4.juniper2.rz13.hetzner.de (213.239.224.97) [AS24940]  0.246 ms hos-tr3.juniper2.rz13.hetzner.de (213.239.224.65) [AS24940]  0.234 ms hos-tr2.juniper1.rz13.hetzner.de (213.239.224.33) [AS24940]  0.236 ms
 3  core21.hetzner.de (213.239.245.81) [AS24940]  1.203 ms core22.hetzner.de (213.239.245.121) [AS24940]  0.233 ms  0.236 ms
 4  core22.hetzner.de (213.239.245.162) [AS24940]  0.245 ms  0.236 ms core1.hetzner.de (213.239.245.177) [AS24940]  4.808 ms
 5  juniper1.ffm.hetzner.de (213.239.245.5) [AS24940]  4.837 ms core1.hetzner.de (213.239.245.177) [AS24940]  4.843 ms  4.825 ms
 6  dec-ix-c01.wvfiber.net (80.81.192.220)  6.174 ms  6.230 ms juniper1.ffm.hetzner.de (213.239.245.5) [AS24940]  4.923 ms
 7  dec-ix-c01.wvfiber.net (80.81.192.220)  6.223 ms ams-ten1-4-fra-ten2-1.bboi.net (66.216.50.57) [AS19151, AS19151]  29.457 ms  24.788 ms
 8  ams-ten1-4-fra-ten2-1.bboi.net (66.216.50.57) [AS19151, AS19151]  22.413 ms  19.756 ms ny60-vl2-ams-vl2.bboi.net (66.216.48.217) [AS19151]  109.138 ms
 9  66.216.1.150 (66.216.1.150) [AS19151]  127.527 ms ny60-vl2-ams-vl2.bboi.net (66.216.48.217) [AS19151]  109.68 ms  108.802 ms
10  lv-ten1-3-chi-ten1-6.bboi.net (64.127.128.130) [AS19151]  171.983 ms  171.777 ms *
11  lv-ten1-3-chi-ten1-6.bboi.net (64.127.128.130) [AS19151]  171.794 ms la-ten1-3-lv-ten1-3.bboi.net (66.186.192.21) [AS19151]  178.527 ms  177.967 ms
12  la-ten1-3-lv-ten1-3.bboi.net (66.186.192.21) [AS19151]  178.478 ms  178.82 ms 66.186.197.174 (66.186.197.174) [AS19151]  178.281 ms
13  colo-lax6 (96.44.180.102) [AS29761]  178.17 ms 66.186.197.174 (66.186.197.174) [AS19151]  177.716 ms  177.935 ms
14  lax-qn-gw.as36236.net (72.11.150.122) [AS29761]  177.709 ms  177.764 ms colo-lax6 (96.44.180.102) [AS29761]  184.72 ms
15  lax-qn-gw.as36236.net (72.11.150.122) [AS29761]  178.34 ms 208.111.40.5 (208.111.40.5) [AS36236]  175.688 ms  175.351 ms
16  208.111.40.5 (208.111.40.5) [AS36236]  175.641 ms  175.919 ms ns1.r4ns.com (176.124.112.100) [AS61163 198412]  176.590 ms
```

Whereas from San Jose, California, it goes to Romania:

```
traceroute to ns1.r4ns.com (176.124.112.100), 16 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  23.92.24.3 (23.92.24.3) [*]  0.574 ms  0.704 ms  0.846 ms
 2  23.92.24.2 (23.92.24.2) [*]  0.464 ms  0.589 ms  0.749 ms
 3  10gigabitethernet7-6.core3.fmt2.he.net (65.49.10.217) [AS6939]  0.256 ms  0.263 ms  0.245 ms
 4  10gigabitethernet4-3.core1.dal1.he.net (72.52.92.154) [AS6939]  45.442 ms  45.436 ms  45.483 ms
 5  10gigabitethernet5-4.core1.atl1.he.net (184.105.213.114) [AS6939]  65.805 ms  65.797 ms  65.757 ms
 6  10gigabitethernet16-5.core1.ash1.he.net (184.105.213.109) [AS6939]  74.565 ms  74.552 ms  74.537 ms
 7  10gigabitethernet9-2.core1.par2.he.net (184.105.213.94) [AS6939]  163.530 ms  163.534 ms  163.515 ms
 8  10gigabitethernet15-1.core1.fra1.he.net (72.52.92.25) [AS6939]  161.999 ms  163.440 ms  161.952 ms
 9  * * 10Gbps.de-cix.adnettelecom.ro (80.81.194.100) [AS6695]  225.819 ms
10  * * *
11  cr.adnettelecom.ro (77.232.218.33) [AS5541]  193.016 ms  195.493 ms  250.588 ms
12  10gbps.cr5.adnettelecom.ro (77.232.218.102) [AS5541]  249.048 ms  191.119 ms  192.532 ms
13  ns1.r4ns.com (176.124.112.100) [as198412/AS28513/AS33597/AS61163/AS198412]  191.507 ms  246.698 ms  192.140 ms
```

Why is the routing so suboptimal?  Is it because they don't run their own backbone?  Or what is the explanation for such poor routing?